# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: When calling stored procedure from Hibhernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am unable to call SP from hibernate using annotation. Every time i am calling SP hibernate showing error as

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect can not access a member of class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes with modifiers ""
```

Dao class where i calling SP

```
Query q = session.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("callStockStoreProcedure");
```

Entity class

```
@javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "callStockStoreProcedure", query = "{ call TESTP(?) }", resultClass = Quotations.class, hints = {
@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
```

And Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTP 
(
  p_cursor out sys_refcursor
) AS 

begin
   open p_cursor for SELECT * FROM MF_ITEM_TYPE;

END TESTP;
```

Answer (score 1):

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes package has been deprecated in 11g and replaced by oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes

A workaround would be to Create a custom Oracle Dialect and using ./core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle9Dialect.java as an example and change

```
Class types = ReflectHelper.classForName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes");
oracletypes_cursor_value = types.getField("CURSOR").getInt(types.newInstance());
```

to

```
Class types = ReflectHelper.classForName("oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes");
oracletypes_cursor_value = types.getField("CURSOR").getInt(null);
```

Alternatively, downgrade the oracle driver version if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is similar with Hibernate bugs: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3682,
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3449

Fix Versions you can find: 
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3159